# c++ measuring execution time

Tags: c++, performance, benchmarking

EDIT: the code was modified following the advices givven to me.

The purpose of the following code is to measure the execution time of  a simple operation (1+1) and of a call to a function who does nothing (foo).

1. The code compiles and seeme to work properly, but the results i am getting are weird - it seems the basic operation requires about the same time as the function call, and most times it take even a little bit more time.
2. Another issue is that the execution time do not seem to be affected by the number of itterrations - it could be 100K or 100M but the times are basically the same.  Also, if I pick a number over one billion, it seeme the execuition time decreases.

i could not find on google what i need - i must time a simple opertaion and an empty function, which should be in the same file as measureTimes() is, or at least - each measuring function should be contained wholy in a single file (and besides, moving foo() to another file actually reduced times so far

right now, this is the output of  my program:

instructionTimeNanoSecond: 1.9

functionTimeNanoSecond: 1.627

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/time.h>
    #include <math.h>

    #include "osm.h"

    #define INVALID_ITERATIONS 0
    #define DEFAULT_ITERATIONS 1000
    #define HOST_NAME_LEN 100
    #define TO_NANO 1000
    #define  TO_MICRO 1000000
    #define  ROLL 10

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        unsigned int iterations = (unsigned int) pow( 10, 9);

        measureTimes( iterations, iterations, iterations, iterations );

        return 0;
    }

    void foo();

    timeMeasurmentStructure measureTimes (unsigned int operation_iterations,
                                          unsigned int function_iterations,
    )
        {

    double functionTimeNanoSecond;

    functionTimeNanoSecond = osm_function_time( function_iterations);
    cout << "functionTimeNanoSecond: " << functionTimeNanoSecond << "\n";;

    double instructionTimeNanoSecond;

    instructionTimeNanoSecond = osm_operation_time( operation_iterations);
    cout << "instructionTimeNanoSecond: " << instructionTimeNanoSecond << "\n";





}

    double osm_operation_time(unsigned int iterations)
    {
        timeval start;
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    int x=0;
    for( int i = 0; i < iterations/ROLL; i++ )
    {
        x=x+1;
        x=x+1;
        x=x+1;
        x=x+1;
        x=x+1;
        x=x+1;
        x=x+1;
        x=x+1;
        x=x+1;
        x=x+1;
    }

    timeval end;
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    timeval diff;
    timersub(&end, &start, &diff);

   // double micro_seconds =(double) (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec);

    double ret =((double) diff.tv_sec*TO_MICRO + diff.tv_usec) / ((double) iterations);


    return ret * TO_NANO;
}

double osm_function_time(unsigned int iterations)
{
    timeval start;
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    for( int i = 0; i < iterations/ROLL; i++ )
    {
        foo();
        foo();
        foo();
        foo();
        foo();
        foo();
        foo();
        foo();
        foo();
        foo();
    }

    timeval end;
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    timeval diff;
    timersub(&end, &start, &diff);

    //double micro_seconds = (double)( (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec)*TO_MICRO+(end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec));

    double ret =((double) diff.tv_sec*TO_MICRO + diff.tv_usec) / ((double) iterations);

    return ret * TO_NANO;
}

void foo()
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: Another C with C++ streams ... Anyway, post your compiler flags, since most of your code will probably be optimized out anyway.

Comment: I'd check the assembler output to see if those calls that you want to time are present at all.

Comment: how do you get that? my code compiles succesfully

Comment: Even if the optimizer is turned off (`-O0`), you're assuming the 1+1 costs time, but the `for` loop does not. If you want to measure what's inside the loop, you've got to unroll the loop for some distance, like 10 or 100 times.

Comment: What you're trying to measure really isn't measurable by that method. `1+1;` doesn't translate into any code and a loop that calls an empty function will almost certainly get optimized away. You really should design a better performance test, one that actually does something, to get measurable results.

Comment: Another option is to simply look up the specs of the assembly instructions for a function call and count the number of cycles needed (if you ignore pipelining). A "simple operation" is probably 1 cycle.

Comment: Turning the optimizer off seems to have no effect

Answer (score 1):

In this case compiler is optimizing your code and probably doesn't even execute the for loop because the code inside `1+1` is not affecting the rest of the program.

If you do something like:

```
int x = 0;
for(int i=0;i<iteration;i++)
   x = x + 1;
cout << x;
```

you will get more real results

Comment: Depending on the optimalization level. Compilers are smart nowadays and can optimize a lot of things.

Comment: What is `x`? If you declare a variable inside of the loop and never use it again, the compiler will definitely optimize that out. No smarts required. What you will need to do is declare a `volatile` variable outside of the loop, and then increment that each time through. That will force the optimizer to leave it alone.

Comment: @CodyGray what i meant was to declare x outside the for loop and put that code inside and at the end output it to the user. I just put the simplified version

Comment: is x=x+1 equivalent to 1+1? i must measure a basic operation.

Comment: @proton: 1+1 is already known to the compiler which results in 2 and when it is not assigned to anything else it becomes redundant and compiler will remove the whole code for the sake of optimization. However, x=x+1 is not known at the compile time so compiler will leave it alone

Comment: ok, but x=x+1 also involoves calling x and assigning a new value to it. those are additional opertaions which i am not interested to measure.

Comment: @proton x most probably is in one of the cpu registers and will not move out of it until the end of the loop.

Comment: @proton I checked with the c++ to assembly at https://assembly.ynh.io/ and without optimization flag, there would be a call and return to the function (subsequently) but with -o2 flag there is no call to that function

Comment: @proton: if you are interested in how compiler optimization works, there is a simple tutorial here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compiler_design/compiler_design_code_optimization.htm

Comment: to what difference should i expect?  right no foo() takes 20% less time then the basic operation.

Comment: @proton: each call to foo (un-optimized) generates 5 assembly instructions and each iteration of for loop (un-optimized) generates 4 instructions

Comment: @proton have this solution helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You are always calculating the average.. which should be more or less the same for the no of iterations

```
double ret = diff.tv_usec / ((double) iterations);
```

Comment: I haven't checked your newly edited code, but when you measure time, you divide the time taken with the nr of iterations, So no matter if you increase the iterations, the average will be more or less the same.

Answer (score 0):

The magic word you're looking for is **[profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29)**. It usually is (and should) be supported by your compiler.